# Extracting data from JSON array?

Tags: android, sql, json

{"result":[{"FullName":"Upasiri"}]}

This is what i get when i run my php. I tried doing various things like put this ti a JSONObject and use get methods, but nothing works :/ How can i extract the "Upasiri" from that? Im new to android, so any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Generate POJO classes with http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ (for example), then you can use any JSON serializer to get the Java Objects and get FullName from it. Example how to do it with a GSON you can find here - http://www.javacreed.com/simple-gson-example/

Answer (score 0):

This is your answer

```
JSonArray array = object.getJSonArray ("result");

for (int i=0; i<array.lenght(); i++) {
  JSONObject object= array.getJSONObject(i);

// this is your uripase
  String url = object.getString("FullName");

}
```

Comment: i did exactly this, But i still get the output as ["Upasiri"]. :/ And here what exactly did u mean by "response"?